# Calling x64 DLL function in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I am trying to port a simple cpp example to Delphi. It calls a function from a x64 DLL:

```
// ... header
typedef struct dfuDeviceInfo
{
    char usbIndex[10];                  /**< USB index. */
    int busNumber;                      /**< Bus number. */
    int addressNumber;                  /**< Address number. */
    char productId[100];                /**< Product number. */
    char serialNumber[100];             /**< Serial number. */
    unsigned int dfuVersion;            /**< DFU version. */
}dfuDeviceInfo;

int getDfuDeviceList(dfuDeviceInfo** dfuList,int iPID, int iVID);

// ... in main()
dfuDeviceInfo *dfuList;

    int getDfuListNb = getDfuDeviceList(&dfuList, 0xdf11, 0x0483);
```

In Delphi I ported to:

```
type dfuDeviceInfo = record
    usbIndex: array [0..9] of ansichar;          //**< USB index. */
    busNumber: integer;                          //**< Bus number. */
    addressNumber: integer;                      //**< Address number. */
    productId: array [0..99] of ansichar;        //**< Product number. */
    serialNumber: array [0..99] of ansichar;     //**< Serial number. */
    dfuVersion: longword;                        //**< DFU version. */
end;
type pdfuDeviceInfo = ^dfuDeviceInfo;

var
getDfuDeviceList: function(var dfuList: pointer; iPID: integer; iVID: integer): integer; cdecl = nil;
```

and a quick test, setting up the DLL function, on demand and calling it:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    DLLHandle: THandle;
    dfuList: array of dfuDeviceInfo;
    getDfuListNb: integer;
begin
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('THE.DLL');
  getDfuDeviceList := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'getDfuDeviceList');
  FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);

  SetLength(dfuList,99);
  getDfuListNb := getDfuDeviceList(pdfuDeviceInfo(dfuList), $DF11, $0483);
end;
```

I checked with DLL Viewer and aparently the GetProcAddress() is pointing to the correct address in the DLL, however when the function is called a ACCESS_VIOLATION exception occurs.
What could be causing the issue?

Gabriel

Comment: `typedef struct dfuDeviceInfo { ... } dfuDeviceInfo;` is overwording in C++, looks like C.

Comment: You can't mix 64 bit and 32 bit code, ever.

Comment: Try different calling conventions. Instead of `cdecl ` try `stdcall`

Comment: Tried both stdcall and cdecl, however I believe in x64 there is only one calling convention and any directive you set is ignored. Both the DLL and Delphi compilation are x64.

Comment: @NineBerry calling conventions only apply to 32bit builds, they are ignored in 64bit builds

Comment: NOTE: FreeLibrary(DLLHandle); was placed in the wrong position when copy&paste while typing the question. It actually the last command.

Comment: Then please edit your code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translation is (mostly) correct, although you should double-check the alignment of the record to make sure it matches the same alignment in the C++ code.

But, more importantly, why are you unloading the DLL from memory before calling the function? Don't do that.  You have to leave the DLL loaded until you are done using it.

And also, don't use a Delphi-style dynamic array to receive the DLL's output pointer.  Use a raw pointer instead.  Delphi-style dynamic arrays and C++-style dynamic arrays are not compatible with each other.  The only reason the DLL function would take a `dfuDeviceInfo**` double-pointer is so that it can allocate its own memory for the array and then return the pointer to you (and in fact, the C++ code you have shown is expecting the function to do exactly that).  If the function were expecting you to allocate the array, then it would have taken a `dfuDeviceInfo*` single-pointer instead.

With that said, try this:

```
type
  dfuDeviceInfo = record
    usbIndex: array [0..9] of AnsiChar;          //**< USB index. */
    busNumber: integer;                          //**< Bus number. */
    addressNumber: integer;                      //**< Address number. */
    productId: array [0..99] of AnsiChar;        //**< Product number. */
    serialNumber: array [0..99] of AnsiChar;     //**< Serial number. */
    dfuVersion: UInt32;                          //**< DFU version. */
  end;
  pdfuDeviceInfo = ^dfuDeviceInfo;

var
  getDfuDeviceList: function(var dfuList: pdfuDeviceInfo; iPID: integer; iVID: integer): integer; cdecl = nil;
```

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DLLHandle: THandle;
  dfuList: pdfuDeviceInfo;
  getDfuListNb: integer;
begin
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('THE.DLL');
  if DLLHandle = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;

  try
    getDfuDeviceList := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'getDfuDeviceList');
    if not Assigned(getDfuDeviceList) then RaiseLastOSError;

    dfuList := nil;
    getDfuListNb := getDfuDeviceList(dfuList, $DF11, $0483);

    try
      // use dfuList and getDfuListNb as needed...
    finally
      // free dfuList according to the DLL's requirements,
      // ie by passing it to another function that the
      // DLL exports for this purpose, unless the memory
      // was allocated by an OS memory function, in which
      // case simply call the appropriate OS memory freeing
      // function directly, which should be outlined in
      // the DLL's documentation...
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;
```